# broadcast() multiple times the same df. Is it cached?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In our application, it happens we join the same dataframe multiple times with several other dataframes (not always the same joining column), in separate queries.

This left-hand side df is not very large, so a broadcast hint may be beneficial.

My questions :

- if the same df get broadcast multiple times, will the transfer occur once (the broadcast data is somehow cached on executors), or multiple times ?
- If the join concern different cols will it be cached as well, or what is broadcast depends on the join key ?

Answer (score -1):

The heuristics the Spark optimizer uses change as the product evolves. The only way to know how your join would be handled is via `explain`. Take a look at [this presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/databricks/optimizing-apache-spark-sql-joins) for information on how to optimize your joins.

As for the specific question about repeated broadcast joins of the same dataframe, whether Spark will broadcast the dataframe once or more than once will depend on the memory state of the workers. If the initially broadcast dataframe is still present on the workers, Spark will not broadcast it again (from what I remember of reading the code a while back).

Comment: If you could point what code you're referring to, it would be nice. That's not what I see in spark 2.1 code.

Comment: I know about explain(). Actually, explain() does not know about my code ! Especially it does not know I'm going to repeatedly broadcast the same df over and over. So, if broadcast data is somehow cached, I can hint it to broadcast the right side of my joins...